# Instances resolved conditionally

Tags: dependency-injection, dryioc

I'm writing an editor where some objects depend on an instance of some `IFileFormat` interface.

Depending on the file extension, the actual instance is either an instance of `FileFormat1` class or `FileFormat2` class, both implementing the `IFileFormat` interface.

I would like to have classes which depend on the `IFileFormat` get the instance in the c-tor:

```
class ClientObj {
     public ClientObj(IFileFormat f) { ... }
}
```

Is it possible to somehow register `IFileFormat` dynamically based on the file extension? (which is a string value). Note that the file extension itself is determined at run-time based on the filename of the file selected by the user.

I'm aware I could have a factory injected in the `ClientObj` c-tor which could allow me to determine dynamically the IFileFormat, but it would be nice to somehow depend on only the `IFileFormat` instance, not some factory instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your extension implementations are known at runtime you may register their instances via `UseInstance(new FileExt2())`.

If you want to register all known extensions beforehand but select the one to be injected based on condition, then do:

```cs
container.Register<IFileExt, FileExt1>(setup: Setup.With(condition: req => myCfg.FileExt == "ext1"));
// similar for the rest of implementations
```

**Update**

You may also `Register` the new implementation any time with the `IfAlreadyRegistered.Replace` option. (`UseInstance` implies that by default). Then also don't forget use `Setup.With(asResolutionCall: true)` for the reasons https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/RulesAndDefaultConventions.md#injecting-dependency-asresolutioncall

Comment: Thank you. In your seconds example, the myCfg implies there's some globally available instance which gives a current "state". Which means I'd need to store that state globally. I was wondering if there's another way to do this. Maybe it's a combination of using some features of DryIoc and some architecture

Comment: For example, maybe a way to be say to DryIoc "From now on, resolve the interface I1, I2 to the classes C1, C2". After that, the container resolves any dependency injection of I1 or I2 to C1 and C2 respectively.

Comment: You may Register the new implementation any time with IfAlreadyRegistered.Replace option. (UseInstance implies that by default). Then also don't forget use Setup.With(asResolutionCall: true) for the reasons https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/RulesAndDefaultConventions.md#injecting-dependency-asresolutioncall